# jQuery - hide link/"a" element's text in IE

Tags: jquery

Hi
Suppose I have a code like that:

```
<a style="background: url(button.jpg);" herf="#">test</a>
```

This code will display a link with a button image, In Chrome/FF, the text "test" have not displayed, but in IE, it displayed.

I try to use text-indent: -999px to hide the text "test", and not work, could someone provide an idea for this problem?

Found a solution:
http://schleichermann.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/css-hide-link-text-let-your-images-shine-through/

Thanks you

Comment: i tried the HTML fragment above, and it displayed a text in all the browsers - Chrome/FF/IE. i also noticed that you're using 'herf' - i hope the typo is not in your code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$("a").contents().hide();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could select content of a tag. +1

Comment: I can't get this to work in any major browser: FF 3.6, IE8 and Chrome 8. What am I doing wrong? http://jsbin.com/ifedo3

Comment: You haven't call the jQuery library, download a jQuery file and place <script src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script> before </head> to your code

Comment: @Charles - jQuery is working in this page: http://jsbin.com/ifedo3/4/ . I can get it to work using `$("a").contents().remove();`, or just `$('a').text('');`

Comment: Yes, I have tested the code and you are right. But, when I use $("a").contents().hide(); in the Drupal site, it works.

Answer (score 1):

U can do it with JQUERY :

```
$('a').hide();
```

And if u want to display link :

```
$('a').show();
```

Comment: `hide` will also hide the background image, and won't let you click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

use css atributes to hide the element

```
display:none; visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to hide the text inside elment "a", not hide the element "a"

Comment: Try using only visibility:hidden. The difference between display and visibility is that display hides tag while visibility hides the content. That means, if you use display:none, the document looks like there is no a-tag while with visibility:hidden, the a-tag still takes up the place it did before (width and height) but is rendered as if it had no content.